# Coredata Migration Issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios7, core-data-migration

I have studied about cordata migration from [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration) tutorial

From this tutorial I have implemented Coredata migration successfully. But I have some doubts on this. I have Three xcdatamodel(a1,a2,a3).

Initially there was only one xcdatamodeld with some ManagedObjectModel(with One Entity and some attributes). When I Create another entity on same model, then its crashed with report "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store". then I delete the new Entity from current Model. then I just implemented Coredata Migration. I got two xcdatamodel. I just created another entity in second xcdatamodel then it works fine. Now i want to know that if i don't know what are the changes I made in current model then how can i redo the current model ? To implement core data migration , I will need to redo the current model , then I will need to create new model with new changes. Here my doubt is If i don't know the changes made in current model from model updated in store then how can i know what is the current model in store ?

Sorry for my English.. Thanks for your time to read my question.

Comment: Why would you not "know the changes you made in current model"? You made the changes yourself, so you should know what they are.

Comment: If I made lots of changes that is little difficult to remember OR if code had written by another developer  then how can i find updated model ?

Comment: Are you not using versioning, like git??